# SQLite JDBC Classpath

Tags: java, sqlite, classpath

I'm migrating an **Eclipse project from Windows to Mac**. For some reason, I'm getting a classpath problem specifically on loading the SQLite JDBC driver in MAC. Windows copy is OK.

```
    Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.service.classloading.spi.ClassLoadingException: Specified JDBC Driver org.sqlite.JDBC class not found  at org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.configure(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:107)
```

**Here's what I did:**

1. Displayed System.getProperty("java.class.path") - the result is exactly the same between the PC and MAC. Same JARs and versions being imported, nothing extra nor missing.
2. Initially I was referencing sqlite from the Maven local repository. I took out the actual sqlite-jdbc-3.7.2.jar, moved it into some place and did a direct reference to it in the build path. But the problem remains.

**A few observations:**

In Windows, typing "org.sqlite." in the code gives me a bunch of auto-complete options, while in Mac, it does not give anything.

Other JARs seem to be imported just fine (ex. I have a JodaTime jar and it's working just fine)

Is this a classpath problem, or do I need a Mac distribution of SQLite-JDBC? I don't see any specific jar on on their site. My current copy was downloaded through Maven dependencies.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Even if your classpath is fine for other jars,, have you checked to see that the jdbc driver actually exists there?

Comment: @Einar It's ok now. The only thing I could think of was a corrupted JAR and it turned out to be true. The JAR originally came from my Maven repository.

Comment: I have noticed that Eclipse projects can be quite fragile. Migrating, distributing, importing, exporting and so on will often cause problems you have to fix. Usually the integrity of the code and classpath is kept, but other seemingly random problems occur.

Comment: @Einar I agree. Oftentimes, it's caused by the disturbed links and relationships from the original workspace. It would be nice to have a project-level export, such that everything will be packaged neatly as an Eclipse project archive, ready to open in its new home without any manual tweaking. Instead of working on my task, I wasted almost an hour figuring this out. Thanks for taking interest in my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is fixed.

I simply replaced my current JAR with a fresh copy from xerial.org, and it worked.

Either the initial JAR I got from the Maven dependency download was corrupted, or some file permissions were preventing the JVM from accessing the JAR's contents.